# How can I implement number of textfields in vertical fashion

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/svQfv.jpg

And also the number of text fields are not fixed.
Any help will be appreciated !!

Edit:

I declared an array of controllers and an array for storing the textfield values.

```
List<StringBuffer> _gpas;
List<TextEditingController> _controllers;
```

And this is how I'm generating the fields

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: widget.semestersDone,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return _createGPAInputField(
              context,
              'Semester ${index + 1}',
              _controllers[index],
              onChanged: _updateCGPA,
            );
          })
```

And this is how I'm trying to access their values in _updateCGPA function

```
void _updateCGPA(dynamic gpa) {
   for (int i = 0; i < widget.semestersDone; ++i) {
     _gpas[i].clear();
     _gpas[i].write(_controllers[i].text);
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: can you show what did you try and did't work for you ?

Comment: @MazinIbrahim added the code please check.